# How do I set the distance between snackbar and floating action button?

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button, snackbar

How do I set the distance between snackbar and floating action button?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't set it !! it's the same as from the bottom plus the `SnackBar` height .

but if you want to adjust it you may not use the FAB from the `Scaffold` but instead make the body a `Stack` and the latest layer is your FAB and wrap it inside a `AnimatedPositioned` so you can animate it with the proper distance from the bottom as you want .

Answer (score 3):

Are you tried

```
floatingActionButton: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end, children: [
  FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _doOrder,
    mini: false,
    elevation: 10,
    child: Icon(EvaIcons.shoppingBagOutline),
  ),
  Container(
    height: 50,
  )
]),
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ScaffoldMessenger I was able to provide a margin to the SnackBar, which gave me the required distance between the SnackBar and the FloatingActionButton.

```
extension ScaffoldMessengerExt on BuildContext {
  ScaffoldFeatureController<SnackBar, SnackBarClosedReason> showInfoSnackBar(
    String message,
  ) {
    final scaffoldMessenger = ScaffoldMessenger.of(this);
    scaffoldMessenger.hideCurrentSnackBar();
    return scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
        content: Text(
          message,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `FloatingActionButton` to always have a bottom padding, you could just wrap it with a `Padding` widget like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.0),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('SnackBar'),
    ),
    body: Builder(
      builder: (context) => RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => _displaySnackBar(context),
        child: Text('Show SnackBar'),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

If you want the `FloatingActionButton` to have a new padding when the `SnackBar` is visible, you could change the padding when you show the `SnackBar` like this:

```
double _fabPadding = 0.0;

_displaySnackBar(BuildContext context) {
  final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('SnackBar'));
  setState(() {
    _fabPadding = 40.0;
  });
  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar).closed.then((_) {
    setState(() {
      _fabPadding = 0.0;
    });
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: _fabPadding),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('SnackBar'),
    ),
    body: Builder(
      builder: (context) => RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => _displaySnackBar(context),
        child: Text('Show SnackBar'),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

---

**Edit:** If you want to avoid the `SnackBar` push the position of the `FloatingActionButton` you could set the behavior property of the `SnackBar` to `SnackBarBehavior.floating`

[SnackBarBehavior](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBarBehavior-class.html)

> floating → const SnackBarBehavior This behavior will cause SnackBar to
>   be shown above other widgets in the Scaffold. This includes being
>   displayed above a BottomNavigationBar and a FloatingActionButton.

Comment: This is not the solution to the distance.

When the snackbar is visible, the distance between the snackbar and the FAB opens up to the first padding value of the FAB.

For example, the first FAB padding height value is 50.0. I want to keep 50 when the snack bar is visible. Keep it in the same place.

Comment: I moved FAB from scaffold's FAB properties to Stack widget in scaffold's body properties. I can use it this way.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer.

Comment: I've tried before but when the snack bar sliding up, caused FAB to jump. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem good.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to set : behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating
It may worked

```
SnackBar(behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating, content: Padding(child: Text(message),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the snackbar to the scaffold with a key.

eg:-

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

void showSnackBar(String text) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        text,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 0, milliseconds: 750),
    ));
  }
```

And then add the key to the scaffold:

```
Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      ...
);
```

You can now call this function from anywhere.